# Basic thread creation - Thread name incorrect

Tags: java, multithreading

I am starting to learn threads. I have tried different types of thread creation. From the below code you can see the thread t4, target is new instance of Mythread1 & thread name is "Thread4".

But when I see the output I am not able to find the Thread name "Thread 4" instead I get the name "Thread-4". But this is a naming convention for a default thread name.

I am not able to understand what's wrong. I am sure its very basic mistake. Kindly correct me.

```
class MyThread1 extends Thread {
    MyThread1() {

    }
    public MyThread1(String nameIn) {
        super(nameIn);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.getName());
    }
}

class MyThread2 implements Runnable {
    Thread ownThread;

    public MyThread2() {
    }

    public MyThread2(String nameIn) {
        ownThread = new Thread(this, nameIn);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

public class ThreadCreation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Execution type1, as direct thread object
        MyThread1   t1 = new MyThread1();
        Thread      t2 = new MyThread1();
        Thread      t3 = new Thread(new MyThread1());
        Thread      t4 = new Thread(new MyThread1(), "Thread4");
        Thread      t5 = new MyThread1("Thread5");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();

        //Execution type2, pass the runnable object to thread constructor
        Thread      t11 = new Thread(new MyThread2());
        Thread      t22 = new Thread(new MyThread2(), "Thread22");
        MyThread2   t33 = new MyThread2("Thread33");

        t11.start();
        t22.start();
        t33.ownThread.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

> Thread-0
>   Thread-2
>   Thread-1
>   Thread-4
>   Thread5
>   Thread22
>   Thread-5
>   Thread33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I see the output I am not able to find the Thread name "Thread 4" instead I get the name "Thread-4". But this is a naming convention for a default thread name.

Your problem is in code like this:

> Thread t4 = new Thread(new MyThread1(), "Thread4");

This code is using `MyThread1` as a `Runnable` and *not* as a thread.  So when the `run()` method is called you are then calling `getName()` on the `MyThread1` instance and *not* on the thread that is actually running and calling your `run()` method and whose name is `"Thread4"`.  That is why the `MyThread2` class works because it is using `Thread.currentThread()` to display the true running thread's name.

When you create a thread, either you need to `extend Thread` and start it as `new MyThread1("Thread4")` *or* implement `Runnable` and do `new Thread(new MyRunnable1(), "Thread4");`.  Implementing of `Runnable` is the recommended pattern since it allows you to extend other classes.

You *never* want to do something like `new Thread(new ClassThatExtendsThread(), "name")`.  That creates a fake Java `Thread` instance that is going to just confuse you.

Comment: I understood, no need to pass a Thread class object in place of a runnable object. This creates 2 threads. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't create two _native_ threads but it does create two Java `Thread` objects.  Just one is never started.

Answer (score 0):

In your MyThread1 you print the name of the thread object the method is in. Since you don't specify another name when creating the object, a sequential name "Thread-4" is generated for you.

You should either print the name of the executing thread, like in MyThread2, or create the MyThread1 object with a name:

```
Thread t4 = new Thread(new MyThread1("Thread4"));
```

Comment: Firstly, the solution works. Now if that is the case the next sequential name would be Thread-3 but why Thread-4. How is it working fine for Thread5

Comment: The counter starts from 1, so the name generated for the fourth thread has a 4 not 3. For thread 5 you are already passing a name of your own.

Comment: No the counter starts from 0, Thread t3 take 2 names Thread-2 for new MyThread1() instance and Thread-3 for the t3. if you see my output the  Thread starts from Thread-0

Comment: You are right..  What's happening is that the output is not in source code order: t3 prints out Thread-4 and t4 prints out Thread-5. This is completely normal because the execution order depends on the scheduler and can be completely unpredictable.